# mapM of fn returning m (Either) over Either parameter ends up with nested Eithers

Tags: haskell

An application takes user-input as arguments (say text that might be a numeric ID).
We then want to e.g. fetch something from the database using that ID.
Both of these operations might fail (so we reach for Either) and both involve interaction with the outside world (so IO).

Mapping a monadic action over some structure - `mapM`, easy!

```
type E1 = Either String Int 

fetchFromDb :: Int -> IO E1 
fetchFromDb i = do   
    return $ case (i `mod` 2 == 0) of 
        True  -> Left "Error - evens not allowed" 
        False -> Right (100 + i) 

main :: IO () 
main = do 
    n1 <- fetchFromDb 1 
    n2 <- fetchFromDb 2 
    n3 <- mapRight fetchFromDb ((Right 3)::E1) 
    n4 <- mapM fetchFromDb ((Right 4)::E1) 
    n5 <- mapM fetchFromDb ((Left "No Int at all")::E1) 
    putStrLn $ "n1 = " ++ (show n1) 
    putStrLn $ "n2 = " ++ (show n2) 
    putStrLn $ "n3 = " ++ (show n3)
    putStrLn $ "n4 = " ++ (show n4)
    putStrLn $ "n5 = " ++ (show n5)

n1 = Right 101
n2 = Left "Error - evens not allowed"
n3 = Right (Right 103)
n4 = Right (Left "Error - evens not allowed")
n5 = Left "No Int at all"
```

As can be seen above - in the event of the user supplying a bad `Int` we get the `Left` error you would expect. If we have a valid Int though the `Either` gets nested (which once I thought about the `Monad` instance definition for `Either` made sense).

So - some sort of reduction or folding needs to take place, but I can't quite see how to hook it up and what my initial value would be.

Footnote: I can of course simply extract the desired Int with a suitable `case` expression in this case, but I'm looking at several parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two ways to handle it. The first is to use `EitherT` isntead of `Either`, so you can use it as a monad. This way you can just write monadic code and the `Either's` will merge into one.

The second one (simplier to introduce into existing code) is using the `Control.Monad.join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` which for nested monads (like `Eithers`) gives you a single one.

Comment: Thanks very much - quick response. I'll give this a go tomorrow when I've got some time to play.